# help firefox screen is somewhat invisible

Tags: xorg, firefox

The screen of firefox is somehow invisible. I relooad and reinstall firefox but stil the screen is gone. I can see the menu but really hard to find. You can see the background of my desktop really strange behaviour and i can't find out what is going on.
See pic
[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Are you using NVidia graphics? Try changing the drivers. Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1348440/edit) to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Type `about:config` in the address bar of the Firefox. Accept the risk and continue.
Type `gfx.webrender.force-disabled` in the search bar and change it to 'true'.
Restart the browser.

Comment: @Johnsandman. I noticed your issue is solved. Can you upvote the answer?